# Concrete5 Custom Block

Tags: block, concrete5, concrete

I've done a little Google searching, but not finding anything very in depth. I've used Concrete5 CMS for at least a dozen sites now, but want to get into custom block building. Right now I have a basic image slider on the home page. I want to build a custom block that enables users to choose what images to display and also set a caption for those images. Anyone know of any good tutorials out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:
http://c5blog.jordanlev.com/blog/2011/12/build-a-slideshow-block/

Comment: Hey man, I found your blog post right after I posted this yesterday. Awesome, awesome work, thank you! You have saved myself (and countless others I'm sure) a bunch of time with all your C5 work!